# Spark Unit testing breaking the transformation chaining?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is my transformation function. I want to test it.
Should I break(move) each transformation chain into separate functions and test them separately or just test the whole function or both?

```
private def transform[T](
      spark: SparkSession,
      data: DataFrame
  ) = {
    val beefData = data
      .filter(col("ingredients").contains("beef") || col("name").contains("beef"))
      .withColumn("total_cook_time", col("cookTime") + col("prepTime"))
      .withColumn(
        "difficulty",
        when(col("total_cook_time") < 30, "easy")
          .when(col("total_cook_time") between (30, 60), "medium")
          .when(col("total_cook_time") > 60, "hard")
      )

    beefData.createOrReplaceTempView("BeefRecipes")
    spark
      .sql(
        "select difficulty, avg(total_cook_time) as avg_total_cooking_time from BeefRecipes group by difficulty"
      )
      .show()

  }
```